# Error when deploying custom module sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I encountered an error in `sugarcrm` while deploying a custom module.

```
ERROR: rmdir_recursive(): argument custom/modulebuilder/packages/PointsRedemption is not a file or a dir.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a permissions issue, try `sudo chmod -R 777 custom/modulebuilder` to see if that's what's going on. A better permission setting is probably 755 with the user/group matching whatever the webserver is running as, usually something like www-data:www-data.